# asp.net method for hyperlinking gridview to detailsview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have table A, table B, and table C.  Each table has a "title" field and an "number day" field and other miscellaneous individual fields.  Then there is a monster table with a table A title, table B title, table C title, and number day field.  For example, one row would have a number day of 3 and an entry for table A's title.  (Not all fields are full.  There are a lot of nulls.)  I would like to have the monster view be a GridView with title entries in it hyperlinked to a DetailsView where I can edit or delete table A, B, or C one at a time.

How exactly do I get this to work??? For example, I want every title entry in table A to show up in the monster table and a button/link from the monster table can go to the automatically generated DetailsView of table A.  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out--Master/Detail method -- GridView with DetailsView using GridView's row selectedValue.